# pd.read_html() does not parse floats when reading beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read the infobox from a Wikipedia page on American elections ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election_in_Alabama)) using bs4 and Pandas. My code is supposed to extract the infobox as a `BeautifulSoup` object and then transform it into a `pd.DataFrame` using `pd.read_html()`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
   

def url_to_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{url}"
    url = requests.get(url).content
    return BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")


def get_infobox(url: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    soup = url_to_soup(url)
    infobox = soup.find("td", {"class": "infobox-full-data"})
    df = pd.read_html(infobox.prettify(), header=0)[0]
    df = df.transpose()
    return df


def main() -> None:
    url = "2020_United_States_presidential_election_in_Alabama"
    data = get_infobox(url)
    print(data.to_string())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The HTML source being parsed (`infobox.prettify()`) looks like this:

```
<td class="infobox-full-data" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
 <table style="background:transparent; width:100%;">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 6px solid #E81B23;">
     <a class="image" href="/wiki/File:Donald_Trump_official_portrait_(cropped).jpg">
      <img alt="Donald Trump official portrait (cropped).jpg" class="notpageimage" data-file-height="2096" data-file-width="1520" decoding="async" height="200" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Donald_Trump_official_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/145px-Donald_Trump_official_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Donald_Trump_official_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/217px-Donald_Trump_official_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Donald_Trump_official_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/290px-Donald_Trump_official_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg 2x" width="145"/>
     </a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 6px solid #3333FF;">
     <a class="image" href="/wiki/File:Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_(cropped).jpg">
      <img alt="Joe Biden presidential portrait (cropped).jpg" class="notpageimage" data-file-height="1988" data-file-width="1491" decoding="async" height="200" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/150px-Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/225px-Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/300px-Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg 2x" width="150"/>
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th style="width:75px;text-align:left">
     Nominee
    </th>
    <td style="width:75px;text-align:center">
     <b>
      <a href="/wiki/Donald_Trump" title="Donald Trump">
       Donald Trump
      </a>
     </b>
    </td>
    <td style="width:75px;text-align:center">
     <a href="/wiki/Joe_Biden" title="Joe Biden">
      Joe Biden
     </a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
    </td>
   </tr>
...
   <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left">
     Percentage
    </th>
    <td style="width:75px;text-align:center">
     <b>
      <span data-sort-value="7001620316431668648♠" style="display:none">
      </span>
      62.03%
     </b>
    </td>
    <td style="width:75px;text-align:center">
     <span data-sort-value="7001365699902121223♠" style="display:none">
     </span>
     36.57%
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</td>
```

The end result looks like this:

```
                       0           1           2              3               4             5           6
Unnamed: 0       Nominee       Party  Home state   Running mate  Electoral vote  Popular vote  Percentage
Unnamed: 1  Donald Trump  Republican     Florida     Mike Pence               9       1441170         NaN
Unnamed: 2     Joe Biden  Democratic    Delaware  Kamala Harris               0        849624         NaN
Unnamed: 3           NaN         NaN         NaN            NaN             NaN           NaN         NaN
```

As you see, the `Percentage` column is full of NaNs instead of actual percentages (what's expected is 62.03%, 36.57% and NaN). If I remove the '%' symbol from the HTML source, changing `get_infobox` to the code below, the result is precisely the same.

```
def get_infobox(url: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    soup = url_to_soup(url)
    infobox = soup.find("td", {"class": "infobox-full-data"})
    infobox_html = infobox.prettify()
    infobox_html = infobox_html.replace("%", "")
    df = pd.read_html(infobox_html, header=0)[0]
    df = df.transpose()
    return df
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `infobox`, you can use:

```
data = {}
for row in infobox.find_all('tr'):
    header = row.find('th')
    if header:
        header = header.text.strip().replace('\xa0', ' ')
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        data[header] = [text for col in cols if (text := col.text.strip())]

# Build and clean dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
df['Popular vote'] = df['Popular vote'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
df['Electoral vote'] = df['Electoral vote'].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Nominee       Party Home state   Running mate  Electoral vote  Popular vote  Percentage
0  Donald Trump  Republican    Florida     Mike Pence               9       1441170       62.03
1     Joe Biden  Democratic   Delaware  Kamala Harris               0        849624       36.57

>>> df.dtypes
Nominee            object
Party              object
Home state         object
Running mate       object
Electoral vote      int64
Popular vote        int64
Percentage        float64
```